# coverageThreshold for Jest with Lerna and yarn workspace not working

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn workspace with Lerna for a React project.  Im using Jest.

When I change the directory to packages/test-package-a, and then run `yarn run test`, which is `"test": "jest"` in the test-package-a package.json file, I see the code coverage report and the task fails because the coverage threshold is not met for unit test coverage.

At the root of the project, not in the packages folder, I run `yarn run test:all` which runs:  `lerna run test`, I see the code coverage report for a test-package-a and the thresholds are below 100%, but the task does not fail even though the coverage threshold is not met for unit test coverage.

Does anyone know how to configure Lerna to understand a non 0 status code from Jest's coverageThreshold?